# adding gradients in tensorflow? grads_and_vars computed using compute_gradient

Tags: tensorflow

I have computed gradients (using compute_gradient()) grads_and_vars1 and grads_and_vars2. Now I need to add both these gradients and store in grads_and_vars3 and use grads_and_vars3 to apply gradients.

but grads_and_vars is a tuple. So how can I do this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the `tuple` data type is immutable.

Therefore if you have to "update" a field of a tuple, you have to create a new tuple and overwrite the old one.

Also, if you have to add two tuples, you can't use the `+` operator because it will create a new tuple concatenating the two tuples.

In order to create a new tuple that's the element wise sum of 2 tuples, you can convert them to numpy arrays, then sum them and convert it back tu tuple.
Since grads_and_vars is a list of tuples (gradient, variable) and you want to add only the gradients part, you can loop over these list (that I suppose have the same lenght) and create a new list of (gradient, variable) tuple. I also suppose that `variable` is the same and in the same position in both `grads_and_vars1` and `grads_and_vars2`.

For example, if we have:

```
grads_and_vars1 = [ (1,2), (0,1) , (-1, 1) ]
grads_and_vars2 =  [ (1,2), (0,1) , (-1, 1) ]
```

we can get:

```
grads_and_vars3 = [(grads_and_vars1[idx][0] + grads_and_vars2[idx][0], grads_and_vars1[idx][1]) for idx in range(len(grads_and_vars1))]
```

that's:

```
[(2, 2), (0, 1), (-2, 1)]
```

Comment: I want to add only the gradients and not the variables. Meaning I want to add only first elements of the tuples. BTW each element of the tuple is a tensor.

Comment: Uh ok I misunderstood your question. Do you mean something like that `rads_and_vars3 = tuple(np.array(grads_and_vars1[0]) + np.array(grads_and_vars2[0]))` ? Everything depends on how `grads_and_vars` are structured. However, you could easily loop over the `grads_and_vars` variables and sum each element you want. It will be less elegant (more lines of code) but it will work

Comment: can you please show me the loop over two variables?

Comment: yes, but first can you please show me exactly what the structure of `grads_and_vars1` and `grads_and_vars2` is? Otherwise, I could continue to misbehave you

Comment: Here is an example of scalar addition: # grads_and_vars is a list of tuples (gradient, variable). Do whatever you
# need to the 'gradient' part, for example, subtract each of them by 1.
subtracted_grads_and_vars = [(gv[0] - 1.0, gv[1]) for gv in grads_and_vars]

Comment: I edited my answer, I also added a numerical example. Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: You're welcome. If I solved your problem, please remember to accept the answer!